# There should be exactly one item with [Dropdown Button]'s value: Instance of 'ProductModel'

Tags: flutter, dart

When i select category the items will show based on the category but when i submit in the products dropdown getting error

Here is my Code...please help guys.

```
 Widget _prepareCategoryDDL() {
    return Container(
      width: 350,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, .3),
              blurRadius: 20,
              offset: Offset(0, 10))
        ],
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<CategoryModel>(
        hint: Text("  Categories"),
        value: this._selectedCategory,
        onChanged: (CategoryModel value) {
          setState(() {
            this._selectedCategory = value;
            this._filteredstoreProdList = widget.userData.products
                .where((data) => data.categoryId == value.id)
                .toList();
          });
        },
        items: widget.userData.categories.map((CategoryModel category) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<CategoryModel>(
            value: category,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "  " + category.name,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _prepareProductsDDL() {
    return Container(
      width: 350,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, .3),
            blurRadius: 20,
            offset: Offset(0, 10),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<ProductModel>(
        hint: Text("  Product"),
        value: this._selectedProducts,
        onChanged: (ProductModel value) {
          setState(
            () {
              this._selectedProducts = value;
            },
          );
        },
        items: this._filteredstoreProdList.map((ProductModel product) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<ProductModel>(
            value: product,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  product.name.length > 30
                      ? "  " + product.name.substring(0, 30)
                      : product.name,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am trying to create a dropdown button in Flutter. I am getting a List from my json then I pass the list to my dropdownButton everything works the data is shown as intended but when I choose an element from it I get this error:

Error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'ProductModel'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
package:flutter/…/material/dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 890 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

```
I tried to get selected product according to category when i do that error is comming 
when i tried widget.userdata.products there is no erro but all the products are coming not according to the category..
```

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate values in the list you're passing to the `items` property.

If that list is dynamic, you can try removing the duplicates.

You can just convert the `List` to `Set` which will remove the duplicate items.

E.g.:

```dart
items: myList.map(...).toSet().toList()
```